# How to add Product image attribute in Magento2.2.5?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, image, backend

I have created Product image attribute in Backend in Magento2.2.5.

**Refer my screenshot**

[image]

But I am not able to see in Product detail page in Admin side.

Is there any other way to do this or I am missing something.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you assigned the attribute to the attribute set ?

Comment: I have assigned. But not showing in Product page..

Comment: Did you run reindex ?

Comment: Yup I have done everything..But it's not reflecting in Product page.

Comment: can you update in the question the install script ?

Comment: By adding a product attribute here, it will automatically reflect in Admin Product page. But only for media attribute it is not reflecting. I don't know what is the reason, so I have not written any script for this.

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example you have created custom image attribute.

attribute code is `test_img`.

attribute label is `Test Image`.

You can upload the image in **"Images And Videos"** tab. Then click on the image you will see new role **"Test Image"** select only that. And check **"Hide from Product Page"**.

And then if you want to display it on product page. Just to test I have placed this code in core file **addtocart.pthml** after this line `<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>`

```
<img src="<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl().'pub/media/catalog/product'.$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('test_img')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Now i got it , creating an attribute as Media Image , does create it as a role . 
You will see it when you click **Add Video**
[image] when editing a product in admin https://d.pr/free/i/KRUV0J .